# Possibility of Auto CAD drawing using ASP.Net Web API

Tags: .net, api, drawing, cad

I would like to know the possibility of drawing the Auto CAD 3D shapes using ASP.Net. I have came across some blogs which tells that could convert the CAD files to PDF files and i didn't get any info about drawing Auto CAD shapes using .net. Also i would like to know the possibility for drawing kind of below image.

Kindly let me know is there any API available in .net to achieve this and If API avaiable for Web version that would be appreciable.

[image]

Comment: There is no standard API in .NET for these files

Answer (score 0):

There are many [software components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit) out there that can create DWG/DXF files. You need to search on Google for `.NET CAD components`.

Once you create the DWG/DXF file you can easily serve it as a download or convert it to PDF file format and allow PDF download.

Answer (score 0):

There are several commercial libraries supporting CAD files display and a free [iFrame plugin](https://beta.sharecad.org/home/OnlinePlugin) that is able to show CAD

Comment: I am looking for create a CAD shapes not for displaying files

Comment: Creating 2D is possible in commercial libraries like e.g. CAD .NET from CADSoftTools, though I am not sure they support that for web.